# AJAX call sending JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am working on a chat system which refreshes automatically using AJAX. First I was using the jQuery $.post function, but since i wanted to return JSON data from my PHP script, i want to use the $.ajax function. My script worked well using the $.post function, but i can not return JSON. This is the relevant code:
Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pages/loadmessage.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"c": getUrlParameter("c"), "t": messagetime},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(pData){
        console.log(pData);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error + status);
    }
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
require_once("../init.php");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if (Input::exists() && Input::get("c") && Input::get("t")) {
    $chat = new Chat($user->data()->ID, Input::get("c"));
    $messages = $chat->getNewMessages(Input::get("t"), $user->data()->ID);
    if ($messages) {
        $result = array(
            'topic' => $chat->getTopic(),
            'messages' => array()
        );
        foreach($messages as $m) {
            array_push($result['messages'], array('source' => 'mine', 'Text' => $m->Text));
        }
        echo json_encode("string!!!");
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode("string" . Input::get("c") . Input::get("t") . Input::exists());
}
?>
```

I already tried to set the contentType of the AJAX call to "application/json" and convert the data to JSON using JSON.stringify, but then no input data gets to the PHP script. The code works if just one parameter (data: {"c": getUrlParameter("c")}) is sent to the PHP script...
I already searched StackOverflow, but i could not find a solution...

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the last parameter of [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) ?

Comment: any error message in console

Comment: `$.post` can return JSON, you just have to use the right syntax: `$.post( "pages/loadmessage.php", {"c": getUrlParameter("c"), "t": messagetime}, function( pData ) {/*do stuff*/}, "json");`

Comment: $.post is just a wrapper for .ajax. And so does work fine with json

Comment: You said this "using JSON.stringify, but then no input data gets to the PHP script" if that is the case you should use this to capture the json string on the server side. $rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");

  // this returns null if not valid json
  return json_decode($rawData);

Answer (score 1):

JSON example:

Index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
        url: "out.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"param1": "test 1", "param2": "test2"},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            alert("param1:"+data.param1+" | param2:"+data.param2);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error + status);
        }
    });
</script>
```

out.php

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["param1"])){ $param1 = $_POST["param1"];}
    if(isset($_POST["param2"])){ $param2 = $_POST["param2"];}

    $out = array("param1"=>$param1,"param2"=>$param2);

    echo(json_encode($out));
?>
```